# SP13: Document Library Check-in/out settings

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-foundation, document-library

Recently our network went down and after it came back up a few of the document libraries lost its functionality.  Prior to the shutdown, when an end-user checked out a pdf and made changes to the pdf the system always prompted the end-user to save and asked if the document can be checked back into SharePoint.  However, the system does not prompt the user anymore to save or check the document in.  This causes the user to save the document to their desktop and reload the document to the library.  I know this has to be a setting to the library that has been turned out.  However, I do not know where to start whether in the library settings or site settings.

Do you know how to turn check-in and check-out settings to a document library?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to run the SharePoint health analyzer and find error from there.

Here is msdn article. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534957(v=office.14).aspx

Install ULS viewer from codeplex (https://ulsviewer.codeplex.com/releases/view/19835). and try to find possible error from there.